# I want to add more criteria's in Sumproduct formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

[image: Burn rate information]

I want to add more criteria's in sumproduct formula as per column G and H, can somebody help?

Eg.

- Output required in col D = Amount Burn till Billing Month (Criteria Team, PO No, Billing Month)
- Output required in col E = Forecast after billing month and till PO in hand month (Criteria Team, PO No, Billing Month, PO in Hand month)

I tried using below sumproduct formula but couldn't able to add month criterias.
formula in cell D3 `= SUMPRODUCT(($A$11:$A$18=$A3)*($B$11:$B$18=$B3)*($C$11:$E$18))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain exactly what you want:

Perhaps a method to return that part of your table that starts at Column C, and extends rightward depending on the date entered in Column H?

If that is the case, that part of the formula would be:

```
$C$11:$C$18:INDEX($11:$18,0,MATCH($H3,$10:$10))
```

With Jun in H3, that formula would return this array:

[image]

So your formula in `D3` would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$11:$A$18=$A3)*($B$11:$B$18=$B3)*$C$11:$C$18:INDEX($11:$18,0,MATCH($H3,$10:$10)))
```

and if you fill down, you get the same results as you show now in column D.

If you change a value in Column H, column D will change accordingly.

Using similar logic, I would expect:

```
E3: =SUMPRODUCT(($A$11:$A$18=$A3)*($B$11:$B$18=$B3)*INDEX($11:$18,0,1+MATCH($H3,$10:$10)):INDEX($11:$18,0,MATCH($G3,$10:$10)))
```

As you can see, this creates the same results as you show in your example:

[image]

Comment: your assumption is correct. I tried your formula and its working fine. thank you for help. Cheers :)